# Neo4j: invalid arguments in CreateRelationship

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm experimenting with the Neo4jClient in C# and am stuck at the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Neo4jClient.IGraphClient.CreateRelationship(Neo4jClient.NodeReference, GraphDB.PrecedesRelationshipo)' has some invalid arguments.

This error is for the line with the following code:

```
client.CreateRelationship<Process,PrecedesRelationship>(prevProcess, new PrecedesRelationship(currProcess, new PrecedesData(product, isOptional)));
```

Here, prevProcess and currProcess are both of type Neo4jClient.NodeReference. Actually, I generate the nodes and store their NodeReference values in a dictionary, so that I can easily look them up. The nodes are created just fine.

Below are my classes:

```
public class Process
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

,

```
public class PrecedesData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOptional { get; set; }

    public PrecedesData()
    { }

    public PrecedesData(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsOptional = false;
    }

    public PrecedesData(string name, bool isOptional)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsOptional = IsOptional;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class PrecedesRelationship : Relationship<PrecedesData>, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Process>,
IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Process>
{
    public static readonly string TypeKey = "PRECEDES";

    public PrecedesRelationship(NodeReference targetNode, PrecedesData data)
        : base(targetNode, data)
    { }

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return TypeKey; }
    }
}
```

When I leave out the types in CreateRelationship I get the error that the compiler cannot infer the types.

I looked at the examples on the Neo4jClient Wiki and I thought I got it right but I seem to be mistaken.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I figured it out: prevProcess and currProcess need to be of type NodeReference<Process> and not just NodeReference. Then it works!

Comment: Just for other people who come across, could you put the code for the `PrecedesRelationship` class in? I think you accidentally pasted `PrecedesData` twice :)

Comment: Oops, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Cypher, as the REST API is increasingly legacy. Really, anything non-Cypher is becoming legacy.

```
client.Cypher
    .Start(new { prevProcess, currProcess })
    .CreateUnique("prevProcess-[:PRECEDES {precedes}]->currProcess")
    .WithParams(new { precedes = new PrecedesData(product, isOptional) })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Then, you don't need any relationship classes either.

Also, if you remove the excess constructors, you can shorten the entire code sample down to just this:

```
public class PrecedesData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOptional { get; set; }
}

client.Cypher
    .Start(new { prevProcess, currProcess })
    .CreateUnique("prevProcess-[:PRECEDES {precedes}]->currProcess")
    .WithParams(new { precedes = new PrecedesData { Name = product, IsOptional = isOptional } })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```